# Calling controller's update on a custom form in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a custom edit.html.erb form and I would like to it to call controller's update

This is the code I'm using for form

`<%= form_tag('/schedules/1', :class => "edit_schedule") do %>`

I'm getting "No route matches "/schedules/1" error.

Comment: what is html output and `rake poutes CONTROLLER='shedules'`

Comment: Have you checked your routes.rb? Is schedules a resource?

Comment: edit_schedule GET    /schedules/:id/edit(.:format) {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"schedules"} - That's the output of rake routes CONTROLLER='schedules'. I do have resources :schedules in my routes.rb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

In controller edit action

```
def edit
  @schedule = Schedule.find(1)
end
```

In view edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_tag(@schedule, :class => "edit_schedule", :method => :put) do %>
```

In routes.rb

```
resources :schedules
```

Comment: I don't know if this makes a difference but I'm trying to edit multiple schedules objects in 1 edit form. I usually have an artificial id in the url like /schedules/daily/edit. I already modified edit in controller to not look for an Schedule.find(1)

Comment: I'm getting No route matches "/schedules/daily/edit". This is what the html looks like: action="/schedules/daily/edit?class=edit_schedule&amp;url=%2Fschedules%2F1%2Fedit" method="post"

Comment: Then change to <%= form_tag(schedule_path(:id => 1), :class => "edit_schedule", :method => :put) do %>

Comment: form_tag(schedule_path(:id => 1), :class => "edit_schedule", :method => :put) worked! thx